# How to retrieve datas from JSON to a combo box?

Tags: php, json

below codes is json(a part only) , I have to put into a combo box whole currencies.

```
{
    "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham",
    "AFN": "Afghan Afghani",
    "ALL": "Albanian Lek",
    "AMD": "Armenian Dram",
    "ANG": "Netherlands Antillean Guilder",
    "AOA": "Angolan Kwanza",
    "ARS": "Argentine Peso"
}
```

I have try up to here...

```
$ch2 = curl_init("http://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Get the data:
$json2 = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);

$currency->LKR; // Here I can retreive a single line

// Decode JSON response:
$currency = json_decode($json2);
```

I have to put into a combo box whole currencies.

Comment: You'll need to loop through the array and create it

Comment: `foreach ($currency as $key => $val)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your $currency arrays looks like

```
$currency = array('AED' => 'United Arab Emirates Dirham' ...... );
```

//then just do foreach

```
$opts = '';
foreach($currency as $key => $val)
{

$opts .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val.'</option>';
}

echo  '<select name="currency">'.$opts.'</select>;
```

Thiss should output something like ...

```
<select name="currency">
<option value="AED">United Arab Emirates Dirham</option>
<option value="AFN">Afghan Afghani</option>

.....

</select>
```

Comment: I was click on rite mark but it was too early I think ... A message popup After 5 mins only I can tick it :) . Now I did it .. thanx